Managing unseen categorical levels in predictive modeling with mlr3
I have trained a glmnet model using data that includes a categorical variable as a predictor, with the mlr3 package.
I am trying to make predictions using the glmnet model on new data.
The categorical variable refers to habitat types, and the response variable corresponds to species presence/absence data.
The new dataset contains habitat types that are not included in the training data.
However, I don’t understand how there can be predictions with probability > 0.5 for habitats that are included in the new dataset (e.g., habitats in the northernmost part of the study area) but were not included in the training data.
I would have liked the predictions for habitat types in the new dataset that are not in the training dataset to be set to 0. I thought I could achieve this with:
mlr3pipelines::po("imputeconstant", param_vals = list(constant = 0, affect_columns = selector_grep("habitat_2")))

but it doesn’t seem to work.
Here is my code:
set.seed(1, kind="Mersenne-Twister", normal.kind="Inversion")
data <- read.csv("C:/Users/Downloads/data_species_1.csv")
new_data <- read.csv("C:/Users/Downloads/new_data_species_1.csv")
data$presence <- as.factor(data$presence)
data$habitat_2 <- as.factor(data$habitat_2)
table(data$habitat_2)
classif_task_sp <- mlr3spatial::as_task_classif_st(id = "A1", x = data[, which(!(names(data) %in% c("ID", "year")))], target = "presence", positive = "1", 
                                                   coordinate_names = c("x", "y"), crs = "EPSG:4326", coords_as_features = FALSE)
classif_task_sp$set_col_roles("presence", roles = c("target", "stratum"))
partition_classif_task_sp <- mlr3::partition(classif_task_sp, ratio = 0.67)

factor_encoding <- mlr3pipelines::po("fixfactors", id = "po_factor_alignment") %>>%
  ## mlr3pipelines::po("imputeconstant", param_vals = list(constant = 0, affect_columns = selector_grep("level_2_ecoregion_type"))) %>>%
  ## mlr3pipelines::po("imputeoor", affect_columns = selector_type("factor"), id = "po_factor_imputation") %>>%
  ## mlr3pipelines::po("imputesample", affect_columns = selector_type(c("ordered", "factor"))) %>>%
  mlr3pipelines::po("encodeimpact", affect_columns = selector_cardinality_greater_than(10), id = "high_cardinality_encoding") %>>%
  mlr3pipelines::po("encode", method = "one-hot", affect_columns = selector_cardinality_greater_than(2), id = "low_cardinality_encoding") %>>%
  mlr3pipelines::po("encode", method = "treatment", affect_columns = selector_type("factor"), id = "binary_encoding") %>>%
  mlr3pipelines::po("imputeconstant", param_vals = list(constant = 0, affect_columns = selector_grep("habitat_2")))
## print(factor_encoding)

learner_glmnet <- mlr3tuningspaces::lts(mlr3::lrn("classif.glmnet", predict_type = "prob", standardize = FALSE))
learner_glmnet_factor_encoding <- mlr3::as_learner(factor_encoding %>>% learner_glmnet)

tuning <- mlr3tuning::auto_tuner(tuner = mlr3tuning::tnr("grid_search", resolution = 5, batch_size = 10),
                                 learner = learner_glmnet_factor_encoding,
                                 resampling = mlr3::rsmp("spcv_coords", folds = 2),
                                 measure = mlr3::msr("classif.prauc"),
                                 terminator = mlr3tuning::trm("evals", n_evals = 2, k = 0))

run_training <- tuning$train(classif_task_sp, row_ids = partition_classif_task_sp$train)
predictions <- run_training$predict_newdata(newdata = new_data)
new_data$predictions <- predictions$data$prob[,c("1")]
test <- tidyterra::as_spatraster(tibble::as_tibble(new_data[,c("x", "y", "predictions")], xy = TRUE), crs = "EPSG:4326")
plot(test$predictions)

Here are the datasets "data_species_1.csv" and "new_data_species_1.csv.
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/7psn2wgr955tjvb8d6nm9/AFPgbkMhoo9Glb2JX1MttBs?rlkey=cp6u29ivmz9ad1u1090xv5nfx&st=uqvabdg5&dl=0

I’m not sure if it’s correct to do, but maybe you could remove the habitats not seen in your new data

You can't really do anything about things not seen during training. Any model will always give you a wrong prediction for those, but depending on how close the features are to the habitats it has seen during training, the probability can be very high, as you've observed.
